# "Mostest" vs. "most"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs, determiners, superlative-degree

What is the difference between *mostest* and *most*?

Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: "Mostest" can only be used to make near rhymes, like "hostess with the mostest". Otherwise, use "most".

Comment: ..or other rhymes like...erm... "Which of these meats has been processed the mostest?"

Comment: ...in short, *Mostest* is a humorous violation of rules of grammar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Mostest* is not an accepted word, though it is [in some dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mostest) listed as slang.  *Most* is already in superlative form, so adding *-est* is redundant and ungrammatical.  It was popularized, however, in the saying (intentionally ungrammatical, to convey a sense of crude common sense): "getting thar fustest with the mostest".

However, unless you want to appear illiterate, or crack a questionable pun, you should always use *most*, never *mostest*.

Answer (score 3):

The only context in which it is acceptable to use the word "mostest" is immediately after the words "I love you the".  "Bestest" is also acceptable in this context (and no other).

Comment: Plus the situation in @David Schwartz comment of course...

Answer (score 2):

*Mostest* sounds silly, like saying *betterer* or even *more betterer*. You would (should!) only do this for deliberate comedic effect (as Leigh Francis does in the guise of Keith Lemon). It's certainly out of place in any kind of formal setting.

The correct comparative is *more* and the correct superlative is *most*. There's no need to add another *-est* suffix.